# Fixed size array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i have a fixed size array as

```
var fieldNameArray = [String?](count: 4, repeatedValue: nil)
```

i am doing this to search if there is the element in array or not

```
  if let temp = find(fieldNameArray,"profile_picture"){//i get a compile error here
            //remove the data
           ....




        }else{

            println(" //append the value")
           .....

        }
```

But i get a compile time error as

> Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([(String?)],
>   String)'

I think i should unwrap it? How can i do it

**UPDATED**

```
 SRWebClient.POST(registerURl)

            .data(registerImagesArray, fieldName: fieldNameArray, data: parametersToPost)

            .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in//here compile time error


                println("response object: \(response)")
```

Again after i changed my array to fixed size array i got this error

> Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject!, Int)
>   -> Void, failure: (NSError!) -> Void)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For efficiency you should not do what Manav Gabhawala suggests but write a find function yourself:

```
func myFind(array: [String?], value: String) -> Int? {
    for (i, av) in enumerate(array) {
        if av != nil && av! == value {
            return i
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

As Swift compiles to machine code, you will have nearly the same performance as with the standard library’s find.

Comment: yeah i was thinking of that...that takes long time to parse for the compiler at run time?

Comment: @copeME Well, the actual problem is the runtime. Manav Gabhawala’s solution allocates two additional arrays to finally iterate over one of them. When you have many objects in your list that can lead to performance issues.

Comment: @copeME No, the compiler does not allocate objects. The compiler just translates Swift code into machine code. That kind of code the processor understands. (And it might optimize some of your code.)

Comment: so thats the thing Thankyou...i had another issue now that was working before i changed my array to fixed size...please see the updated question..i didnot like to post another question for a simple issue so

Comment: @copeME This is a completely different question. Please ask a new one.

Comment: this was working fine ..it gives me compile time error when i changed the array to fixed size...anyway thanks..i will accept your answer later on

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead (Swift 2.0):

```
if let index = fieldNameArray.indexOf("profile_picture") {
        //remove the data using the index
       ....

} else {
       print("// append the value")
       .....
}
```

In swift 1.2 (a little inefficient but it works) :

```
if let temp = find(fieldNameArray.filter { $0 != nil}.map { $0! },"profile_picture") { 
    // Then same code as question...
```

Comment: No problem. Although note that temp won't be the index that you expect since we are filtering the original array so if you are using it be aware. If you need the index I would recommend using a dictionary of type [Int: String?] that way you get array like notation but with a dictionary instead. If you want to implement it like that let me know and I will update the answer.

Comment: thanks alot...i had another issue now that was working before i changed my array to fixed size...please see the updated question